# What is this "flag" marker in bottom right corner of altas?

Tags: cartography, mapping, global

A relative has a "Political map of the world" on the wall in their house.

It has this "Flag" symbol in the bottom right corner. There are no other symbols like it on the map.

[image: Flag symbol in corner of map]

What is the symbol?

### Unconfirmed ideas

- An indication of the map projection
- A brand mark of the map maker
- Indication to wrap to other side of map
- A rune of some sort (Wynn/Wunjo)

Comment: A reverse image search of this symbol didn't reveal anything usefull. It may be the combination of some other symbols?

Comment: That's made me think of it could be some runic thing?

Comment: Who published the map, and in what year

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that information

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a GIS-centric Question.

Comment: A Symbol of military or navigation purpose?

Comment: Post a picture of the whole map and a close-up picture of any descriptive text on the map.

Answer (score -1):

I did a google image search for "[cartographic symbol military](https://www.google.com/search?q=cartographic%20symbol%20military&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjLgtu11pT6AhXQgc4BHazVB9QQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=cartographic%20symbol%20military&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DkA1jkA2DSCGgAcAB4AIABVIgBlgGSAQEymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=hv0hY8unA9CDur4PrKufoA0&bih=666&biw=1365)" and found this:https://www.pinterest.com/pin/3a36533a096ddc79a31b62d1f50dcb15gif-25042200--275845545910038100/ - 6th symbol from above on the right side that looks like the basic symbol you have and comes with the legend `Battalion CP`:

[image]

[Here again](https://twitter.com/Archer83Able/status/1312869210960343041/photo/1) (see first row, Soviet map marking) the symbol stands for `Battalion`:

[image]